# Promises not resolving synchronously despite awaiting for them

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, mobx, mobx-react

So I have a function that fetches the location and returns a promise. I'm using mobx as a store where I update the `this.locationStoreProp` and `this.hotel.subtext` property.

```
public fetchPropertyLocation(some_input_params): Promise<any> {

    return this.apiSource
      .fetchPropertyLocationData(input)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        runInAction('update from response', () => {
          if (data) {
            this.locationStoreProp = data.location;
            this.hotel.subtext = data.location.score;
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        runInAction('error in location', () => {
          //log event
        });
        return {
          error
        };
      });
  }
```

Now, the issue that the `this.hotel` depends on another fetch operation below. And this needs to resolve before my above promise so that I can set the `subtext` in `this.hotel`. But this `fetchHotelInfo` function is used inside another `fetch`(below it).

```
public fetchHotelInfo(input_params): Promise<any> {

    return this.hotelInfoSource
      .fetch(input)
      .then(data => {
        runInAction('update hotel from response', () => {
          this.hotel = data;
        });

        return data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        runInAction('recovering from hotel info call failure', () => {
          //log event
        });

        return {error};
      });
  }
```

```
  public fetch(input_params) {
    const { hotelId, searchCriteria } = this;

    const infoPromise = this.fetchHotelInfo(input_params);
    const someOtherPromise = this.someOtherOperation(input_params);

    return Promise.all([infoPromise, someOtherPromise])
      .then(
        () =>
          new Promise(resolve => {
            runInAction('updating', () => {

              this.isLoading = false;

              resolve();
            });
          })
      )
      .catch(
        () =>
          new Promise(resolve => {
            runInAction('updating hotel with failure', () => {
              this.isFailure = true;
              resolve();
            });
          })
      );
  }
```

At last, I'm simple awaiting for them. I'd want the `fetch` function promise to resolve first with it's `fetchHotelInfo` promise, but my location function promise getting resolved first and due to it I find the property `this.hotel` undefined.

```
public async fetch(options: FetchOptions): Promise<any> {
 await fetchClassObj.fetch(params);
 await fetchClassObj.fetchPropertyLocation(params);
}
```

What's going wrong here? Thanks.
Also, please don't worry about the syntax.

Comment: Why are you mixing `then` with `await`? Just use one or the other

Comment: well, I need to update some variables in `then`

Comment: `await fetchClassObj.fetch(params).then(() => fetchClassObj.fetchPropertyLocation(params));`

Comment: sinking 5 indent levels to use promises this way is really a travesty of what promises are meant to do! use `async/await` and get rid of those ugly callback trees!

Comment: also the problem is that you're mixing promises with old fashioned callbacks every time you use `runInAction`, which throws the whole point of promises out the window unless you wrap it in a `new Promise` as you do in `fetch`

Comment: @Klaycon Do you mean that I should get rid of `Promises.all()`?

Comment: @Klaycon And why is it wrong to use `runInAction` like this? Can you please explain to me? Thanks.

Comment: @Klaycon I don't think `await/async` is the solution to the callback hell. Promises were developed exactly for that purpose so you could chain them together. `Promise.all` is really also fine.

Comment: @Elias `await/async` is *absolutely* the solution to callback hell. Promises were developed to be "callback containers", they alone don't solve the problem - but with async/await 90% of asynchronous code can be written without a single callback indenting your code ever to the right. `Promise.all` is indeed fine because it serves a specific purpose that async/await can't provide, which is running many promises concurrently, however the rest of the code can be vastly simplified with await.

Comment: @आनंद `Promises.all()` is fine, but you should choose one of either async/await and .then() and try to stick to that in your code. `runInAction` is wrong because you have a callback there that isn't accounted for by the promise, which means at the time the promise resolves, there are still callbacks that haven't been executed yet - that's why `this.hotel` is undefined.

Comment: @Elias See my answer for an example of how `async/await` is the solution to callback hell.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `this.hotel` as undefined because in your promise callbacks, you're calling the function `runInAction` with yet another non-promise callback. When the promise resolves, `runInAction` is still pending and hasn't executed its callback yet. To solve this, I'd recommend making a wrapper function similar to this:

```
function runInActionPromise(status) {
  return new Promise((res,rej) => {
    runInAction(status,res);
  });
}
```

Of course, if `runInAction` is a function you defined, you can also just edit it to use promises instead of callbacks.

Additionally, you should stick to either `async/await` or `Promise.then()` in your code, not mixing both. I'd recommend `async/await` to reduce/eliminate the callback hell that seems to be rampant in your code. You could, for example rewrite `fetchPropertyLocation` like this:

```
public async fetchPropertyLocation(some_input_params): Promise<any> {
  try {
    let { data } = await this.apiSource.fetchPropertyLocationData(input);
    await runInActionPromise('update from response');
    this.locationStoreProp = data.location;
    this.hotel.subtext = data.location.score;
  } catch(error) {
    await runInActionPromise('error in location');
    //log event
    return {error};
  }
}
```

And `fetchHotelInfo` like this:

```
public async fetchHotelInfo(input_params): Promise<any> {
  try {
    let data = await this.hotelInfoSource.fetch(input);
    await runInAction('update hotel from response');
    this.hotel = data;
    return data;
  } catch(error) {
    await runInAction('recovering from hotel info call failure');
    return {error};
  }
}
```

This is significantly more readable and you can use even use "synchronous" error handling with `try/catch`.

Either way you go, as long as you make sure to account for the callback in `runInAction` by wrapping it with a promise everywhere you use it, it should end up working.

Comment: Thanks. But `runInAction` is not defined by me. It's the `mobx` api method.

Comment: Also, can you please point me to some good resources to clear my concepts regarding this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about you do something like this:

***Untested***

```
fetchHotelInfo().then(hotel => {
  this.hotel = hotel;
  return fetchPropertyLocation();
}).then(propertyLocation => {
  this.hotel.prop = propertyLocation.prop;
  this.hotel.bar = propertyLocation.bar;
});
```

Like this you don't have to mix `async/await` and `Promises` plus everything looks pretty tidy. Because `Promises` are somewhat designed to replace `callbacks` it would be nice if you converted your `runInAction` function into one as well.

So:

```
function runInAction(): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(...);
}

.catch(() => runInAction('updating hotel with failure'));
```

As a side effect, this would prevent the chain from being broken, as well as making the whole code look more consistent.

**Important** If you use a callback in the middle of such a chain, it will break the order in which the code gets executed. So don't use callbacks (except if they have a `resolve()` in them) in promises.

Comment: Introducing a callback in the middle of promises causes results that will happen later than the promise resolves. The callback to `runInAction` will execute sometime later, which is exactly when to use promises - so you can catch that result and bring it up with the rest of the asynchronous results.

Comment: Changed the answer

Comment: @Elias can you point me to some good resources to clear my concepts regarding this? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, but if you know promises, nothing should hold you back. Just start using one single API. It makes everything much more readable. If you have any questions, please ask more specific ^^. The promise [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is always a good read.